# How do I build a model to predict which service a customer will use on an app?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, predictive-modeling

There's an app with over 50 services. I have the data on the type of service a specific customer (they have a unique customer number) does on the app, the date, location, time, duration on a service and the volume of that service. 
I want to build a ML model to personalize the services the customer gets daily when they open the app. i.e. Top 6 services they're likely to use for that day
Which machine learning technique would be optimal to achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the most frequent used ones... then explore the need to build a more complex model. Chances are the distribution of service is skewed and you don’t really need to build a model outside a top n.